Google Data Studio is it possible to combine a Stacked Column + Single Column?
I am wondering if this is possible in google data studio, I'm finding a way on how can I combine a stacked column chart and a single column chart using a single dimension, is it possible? I also posted the settings for both charts and my desired result. and oh, my source data is just a simple g-sheets to begin with, just a 3 column to load the dimensions, thanks!!! :)
I'm trying to blend it and I cant get what I wanted it to be
Stack & Single Column Chart
Result that I'm trying to do
